# why java allows importing a class defined in same file?

Tags: java

I created a java file named `TestClass.java` and put it inside a folder `testPackage`. On compilation, importing the same class which I defined in this same file, didn't give me any error.

Why is it allowing to do so ? Is there any real purpose behind this or just a grammar glitch, the impact of which is too low (because of bad practice?) that nobody cares (like more than one `;` after import statement)?

```
package testPackage;
import testPackage.TestClass;
public class TestClass{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("hello world");

    }
}
```

I'm using the below setup :

```
C:\test>tree /F
Folder PATH listing for volume OS
Volume serial number is 2A49-80E2
C:.
└───testPackage
        TestClass.java

C:\test>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_181

C:\test>java -version
java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)

C:\test>javac -cp . testPackage\TestClass.java

C:\test>java testPackage.TestClass
hello world
```

Comment: If I were to guess, I would say it is not implemented for the same reason we do not have multi-inheritance in java: It would have made the compiler more complicated (i.e. it would have been one more check).

Comment: Why not? Is it a problem? Is it worthwhile writing the code to check for this condition into the compiler? What problem would be solved thereby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are cases where it's necessary to `import` a class defined in the same file. Your example surely isn't one of them (your import is simply superfluous because classes in the same package are in the same namespace, which roughly means that classes in the same package are implicitly imported).

But look at this (suppose all code is in the same file):

```
package stackoverflow;

import stackoverflow.OtherClass.OtherClassInner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        OtherClassInner inner = new OtherClassInner();
    }
}

class OtherClass {
    static class OtherClassInner {

    }
}
```

In this case, `Main` is not in the same namespace as `OtherClassInner`, so it either has to fully qualify `stackoverflow.OtherClass.OtherClassInner` (or reference it through `OtherClass.OtherClassInner` as `Main` and `OtherClass` don't need to import one another), or to import it as shown in the above snippet.

And just to make it obvious why the import is necessary, consider this (where there are two `OtherClassInner` in the same file):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        OtherClassInner inner = new OtherClassInner();
    }
}

class OtherClass {
    static class OtherClassInner {

    }
}

class YetAnotherClass {
    static class OtherClassInner {

    }
}
```

Comment: This piece of code will work even without that import statement.

Comment: [It does work without additional imports and without fully qualified class name...](https://ideone.com/XkdM9v)

Comment: @Turing85: In your code your wrote `new OtherClass.OtherClassInner()`. The import lets you do this without that qualifier. That's exactly what imports are for, you can always do without them by putting in a "fuller" name.

Comment: @Thilo I am aware of that. Nevertheless, the statement "*There are cases where it's necessary to import a class defined in the same file*" in the answer is wrong, and my example demonstrates it.

Comment: @Turing85 I see what you're saying (a fully-qualified name is not always necessary because the nested static class can be referenced through its enclosing type) - and have edited. That was my oversight. But using `OtherClassInner` directly requires an import and that was what I want to show here.

Comment: Okay, it is never necessary to import anything, you can always qualify the name. I suppose it was meant to read "necessary to import *in order to use the unqualified name*".

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the compiler profiles the class to be compiled and all imported classes and ensures that multiple different profiled classes don't have the same name in the given scope(ie different files aren't importing different files with classes with the same name). It is highly common for multiple files to import the same class (or same file) and thus this situation is not "incorrect" in that aspect. In such a case the compiler would simply note that it has read a class and so the next time it is included, it realizes that it has already read that class and uses the existing profiled class. After the compiler has profiled each class (likely pre forming the class hierarchy) it goes through and compiles the classes it has profiled.

This method should give the same result as if the given case was handled explicitly but the code is simpler thus leaving less room for errors and increasing performance as well as possibly handling other "strange" situations which may otherwise have result in incorrect compilation due to having to specifically cater for them.

many compilers avoid these situations like the plague as they do not do this profiling step and thus each time situations like this happen they run the risk of causing the compiler to enter an infinite loop as they continually restart compiling the same file each time as they see it as a dependency and thus must be compiled first before they can compile the original (and same) file.